# Creating ArcGIS terrains using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst, terrain

I'm trying create a terrain using ModelBuilder but with "Create Terrain" there is no where to specify SFTypes and when the model is run it give the error:

> The Terrain definition is incomplete or invalid

Can one create terrains in ModelBuilder?

Comment: What is SFTypes? I've done this before in model builder but it's been quite a while.. You are creating the terrain inside a feature dataset with a *known*, preferably projected, coordinate system aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

After you run **Create Terrain** tool, run the **Add Feature Class To Terrain** tool, which allows you to specify **SF Type**